# How can I resolve NuGet.exe command line being unable to install xunit 2.1.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, nuget, xunit

Creating a brand new project in Visual Studio 2013 with update 5 and NuGet Package Manager 2.8.60610.756 can install xunit 2.1.0 perfectly

```
------- Installing...xunit 2.1.0 -------
Attempting to resolve dependency 'xunit.core (= 2.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'xunit.extensibility.core (= 2.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'xunit.abstractions (= 2.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'xunit.extensibility.execution (= 2.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'xunit.assert (= 2.1.0)'.
Installing 'xunit.abstractions 2.0.0'.
Added file 'xunit.abstractions.dll' to folder 'xunit.abstractions.2.0.0\lib\net35'.
Added file 'xunit.abstractions.xml' to folder 'xunit.abstractions.2.0.0\lib\net35'.
Added file 'xunit.abstractions.dll' to folder 'xunit.abstractions.2.0.0\lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+monotouch+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS'.
Added file 'xunit.abstractions.xml' to folder 'xunit.abstractions.2.0.0\lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+monotouch+monoandroid+Xamarin.iOS'.
Added file 'xunit.abstractions.2.0.0.nupkg' to folder 'xunit.abstractions.2.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'xunit.abstractions 2.0.0'.
Installing 'xunit.extensibility.core 2.1.0'.
Added file 'xunit.core.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.core.dll.tdnet' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.core.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.core.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.runner.tdnet.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.runner.utility.desktop.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.core.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.core.dll.tdnet' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.core.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.core.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.runner.tdnet.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.runner.utility.desktop.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0.nupkg' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.core.2.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'xunit.extensibility.core 2.1.0'.
Installing 'xunit.extensibility.execution 2.1.0'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\dnx451'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\dnx451'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\dnx451'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\monoandroid'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\monoandroid'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\monoandroid'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\monotouch'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\monotouch'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\monotouch'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.desktop.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\net45'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.desktop.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\net45'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.desktop.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\net45'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\win8'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\win8'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\win8'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\wp8'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\wp8'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\wp8'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.dll' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\xamarinios'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.pdb' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\xamarinios'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.dotnet.xml' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0\lib\xamarinios'.
Added file 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0.nupkg' to folder 'xunit.extensibility.execution.2.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'xunit.extensibility.execution 2.1.0'.
Installing 'xunit.core 2.1.0'.
Added file '_._' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0\build\dnx451'.
Added file '_._' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0\build\monoandroid'.
Added file '_._' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0\build\monotouch'.
Added file '_._' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0\build\net45'.
Added file 'xunit.core.props' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0\build\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file '_._' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0\build\win8'.
Added file 'xunit.core.props' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0\build\win81'.
Added file '_._' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0\build\wp8'.
Added file 'xunit.core.props' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0\build\wpa81'.
Added file '_._' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0\build\xamarinios'.
Added file 'xunit.execution.desktop.dll' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0\build\_desktop'.
Added file 'xunit.core.2.1.0.nupkg' to folder 'xunit.core.2.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'xunit.core 2.1.0'.
Installing 'xunit.assert 2.1.0'.
Added file 'xunit.assert.dll' to folder 'xunit.assert.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.assert.pdb' to folder 'xunit.assert.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.assert.xml' to folder 'xunit.assert.2.1.0\lib\dotnet'.
Added file 'xunit.assert.dll' to folder 'xunit.assert.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.assert.pdb' to folder 'xunit.assert.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.assert.xml' to folder 'xunit.assert.2.1.0\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'.
Added file 'xunit.assert.2.1.0.nupkg' to folder 'xunit.assert.2.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'xunit.assert 2.1.0'.
Installing 'xunit 2.1.0'.
Added file 'xunit.2.1.0.nupkg' to folder 'xunit.2.1.0'.
Successfully installed 'xunit 2.1.0'.
Adding 'xunit.abstractions 2.0.0' to ClassLibrary1.
For adding package 'xunit.abstractions 2.0.0' to project 'ClassLibrary1' that targets 'net45',
>> Assembly references are being added from 'lib\net35'
Added reference 'xunit.abstractions' to project 'ClassLibrary1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Added file 'packages.config' to project 'ClassLibrary1'
Successfully added 'xunit.abstractions 2.0.0' to ClassLibrary1.
Adding 'xunit.extensibility.core 2.1.0' to ClassLibrary1.
For adding package 'xunit.extensibility.core 2.1.0' to project 'ClassLibrary1' that targets 'net45',
>> Assembly references are being added from 'lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'
Added reference 'xunit.core' to project 'ClassLibrary1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'xunit.extensibility.core 2.1.0' to ClassLibrary1.
Adding 'xunit.extensibility.execution 2.1.0' to ClassLibrary1.
For adding package 'xunit.extensibility.execution 2.1.0' to project 'ClassLibrary1' that targets 'net45',
>> Assembly references are being added from 'lib\net45'
Added reference 'xunit.execution.desktop' to project 'ClassLibrary1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'xunit.extensibility.execution 2.1.0' to ClassLibrary1.
Adding 'xunit.core 2.1.0' to ClassLibrary1.
For adding package 'xunit.core 2.1.0' to project 'ClassLibrary1' that targets 'net45',
>> Build files are being added from 'build\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'xunit.core 2.1.0' to ClassLibrary1.
Adding 'xunit.assert 2.1.0' to ClassLibrary1.
For adding package 'xunit.assert 2.1.0' to project 'ClassLibrary1' that targets 'net45',
>> Assembly references are being added from 'lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81'
Added reference 'xunit.assert' to project 'ClassLibrary1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'xunit.assert 2.1.0' to ClassLibrary1.
Adding 'xunit 2.1.0' to ClassLibrary1.
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'xunit 2.1.0' to ClassLibrary1.
==============================
```

Performing the same install step using the most up to date NuGet Command Line exe (2.8.60717.93) fails stating it requires NuGet 3.0...

```
C:\development\tools\nuget> nuget update -self
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 2.8.6.
NuGet.exe is up to date.
C:\development\tools\nuget> nuget
NuGet Version: 2.8.60717.93
usage: NuGet <command> [args] [options]
Type 'NuGet help <command>' for help on a specific command.

Available commands:

 config      Gets or sets NuGet config values.

 delete      Deletes a package from the server.

 help (?)    Displays general help information and help information about other commands
             .

 install     Installs a package using the specified sources. If no sources are specified
             , all sources defined in the NuGet configuration file are used. If the conf
             iguration file specifies no sources, uses the default NuGet feed.

 list        Displays a list of packages from a given source. If no sources are specifie
             d, all sources defined in %AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config are used. If NuGet.c
             onfig specifies no sources, uses the default NuGet feed.

 pack        Creates a NuGet package based on the specified nuspec or project file.

 push        Pushes a package to the server and publishes it.
             NuGet's default configuration is obtained by loading %AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.
             config, then loading any nuget.config or .nuget\nuget.config starting from
             root of drive and ending in current directory.

 restore     Restores NuGet packages.

 setApiKey   Saves an API key for a given server URL. When no URL is provided API key is
             saved for the NuGet gallery.

 sources     Provides the ability to manage list of sources located in %AppData%\NuGet\N
             uGet.config

 spec        Generates a nuspec for a new package. If this command is run in the same fo
             lder as a project file (.csproj, .vbproj, .fsproj), it will create a tokeni
             zed nuspec file.

 update      Update packages to latest available versions. This command also updates NuG
             et.exe itself.

For more information, visit http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference
C:\development\tools\nuget> nuget install xunit -version 2.1.0
Attempting to resolve dependency 'xunit.core (= 2.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'xunit.extensibility.core (= 2.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'xunit.abstractions (= 2.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'xunit.extensibility.execution (= 2.1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Collections (= 4.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Runtime (= 4.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Diagnostics.Debug (= 4.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Globalization (= 4.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.IO (= 4.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Text.Encoding (= 4.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Threading.Tasks (= 4.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Linq (= 4.0.0)'.
The 'System.Linq 4.0.0' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60717.93'.
C:\development\tools\nuget>
```

Visual Studio doesn't mention the System libraries at all and utilizing the VS2013 "Enable NuGet Package Restore" also works for restoring the packge and its dependencies and is running the same version of NuGet.exe Command Line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot stop NuGet.exe version 2 from failing to download xunit 2.1.0 from the command line using `nuget install xunit -version 2.1.0`.

When you do the same thing in Visual Studio the dependencies that are downloaded are restricted to those that the target framework of your project supports.

When you use `nuget install xunit -version 2.1.0` there is no project so there is no target framework so all dependencies are considered compatible so they will all be downloaded. For xunit 2.1.0 one of its dependencies is System.Linq 4.0.0 which requires NuGet 3.0.

Your workarounds would be:

1. Use a packages.config file instead. The packages.config file would have the target framework information stored in it.
2. Use NuGet.exe version 3.

Comment: Thanks Matt. It would be a great feature to have the ability to define targetFrameworks or NuGet exe detect which frameworks are installed so that one's not prevented from installing a NuGet Package when it offers integration for a framework that isn't being used and/or isn't fully released yet.